# Why am I (sometimes) getting a TypeError using the digital goods sample?

Tags: actions-on-google

I have a deployed action which utilizes digital goods, but I often get a TypeError when user selects the SKU. This has been tested by me as well as quite extensively at Google and this error doesn't happen. Trying to figure out why it is happening now.

I tried initializing the selectedSKUId separately but that did not solve the problem.

```
app.intent('Initiate the Purchase', async (conv, {SKU}) => {
  const selectedSKUId = conv.arguments.get('OPTION') || SKU;
  const selectedSKU = conv.data.skus[selectedSKUId];
```

My SKUId is 'coins' Like I said the error doesn't happen when I test or apparently when the Google team approved my action.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'coins' of undefined at app.intent

Comment: In those cases, are you sure that `conv.data.skus` is valid?

Comment: @NickFelker, it looks like this intent is being called even though the user says "no" when they are giving the option to buy. I'm guessing that is what the async feature does on this? I haven't used async on any my intents before...

Comment: Async doesn't seem like it's needed here, as it is syntactic sugar on top of Promises. But this is more likely an issue related to your intent matching that gets you to this intent.

Comment: Not sure...I am just using the code provided in the samples. I know the correct intent is being triggered when the user says "no" (they don't want to purchase) but it looks like the 'Initiate the Purchase' intent is also being triggered somehow.